# JavaScript build system using in-memory files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I'm currently working with Ember's build tool Ember-CLI so there are a lot of JavaScript source files. But this is a more broadly applicable question.

After a source file changes, there's some time spent building and doing file I/O before tests can be run or a browser refresh can happen.

***Could the file reading be minimized and file writing part be skipped during development?***

So the workflow would be:

1. Start server
2. Process each file (ex. CoffeeScript -> JavaScript -> ES6 transpile -> lint).
3. Store each processed file output in-memory.
4. When a file is changed, process that one file and swap it out in memory. (No file writing.)
5. Concatenate the in-memory files and serve directly to the browser. (Files that didn't change don't need to be read in order to concatenate into a single JS source file.)

Would this be noticeably faster than having all of the file I/O?

Comment: The biggest slow down with most JS build systems (like Grunt) is not that they do I/O but that they actually do a lot of _synchronous_ I/O, they also don't do a particularly good job of tracking dependencies so they might build files that haven't changed over and over. That said, what you suggest is easily testable - put everything on a ramdisk and try it.